# add up all value from array of objects's key after parseFloat()

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

so I have an array of objects inside like this:

```
        let ary = [
            {
                a : 'something',
                b: '2',
                c: 'something'
            },
            {
                a : 'something',
                b: '2',
                c: 'something'
            },
            {
                a : 'something',
                b: '2',
                c: 'something'
            }
        ]
```

I need to add up all key b's value on each object so I first change them to number with parseFloat like this:

```
ary.forEach( item => {
   item.b = parseFloat(item.b)
})
```

Next I use reduce() inside a .map function.

```
let total = ary.map((item, index) => {
    return ary.reduce((a, b) => ({x: a.b + b.b}))
})
```

but I did not get what I want, it return an array of objects with both same total value.

```
array = [
  {x : total},
  {x : total}
]
```

How should I get just single total value? like
total = 2+2+2 and each 2 is from the b key in ary.

Comment: Just strip the `.map()` and only keep the `.reduce()`

Comment: @NinaScholz _"I need to add up all key b's value"_ + _"...get just the total?"_

Comment: @Andreas i get rid of the .map() and got TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
const total = ary.reduce((sum, item) => (sum + parseFloat(item.b)), 0);
```

With one loop you'll invoke `parseFloat` and summ all `b` properties.

Comment: do I need to do it in map or forEach ?

Comment: @andromad `.reduce()` is all you need. No `.map()` or `.forEach()` required.

Comment: thanks it works... actually it really make sense since i got the total twice previously, but I can't really fully understand what is the 0 at the back do. Mind to help me understand more clearly? And Is reduce function the best way to solve this issue in performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

You could chain some methods by separating the value of the objects, take numbers and add all values with reduce.

```js
var array = [{ a: 'something', b: '2', c: 'something' }, { a: 'something', b: '2', c: 'something' }, { a: 'something', b: '2', c: 'something' }],
    sum = array
        .map(({ b }) => b)
        .map(Number)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I am going out now, will try your method later.